# How to output data from a two dimensional array by using binary search C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

One of the functions I am doing uses a binary search for a two dimensional array with 2 rows and 12 columns. The first row is for student IDs, so there are 12 students total. The second row has the corresponding GPA for each student. The part where I am stuck on is using the binary search to display the GPA for one of the 12 students from the 2D array when a user enters in a student ID to search for. I have come up with this for the binary search, but I don't think it will display the corresponding GPA for a student when a user enters in a student ID to search for. Any help would be awesome!

```
        void search(double avg[][COLUMNS])
        int number;      // number is the student ID the user entered already
        int first = 0,
        last = MAX - 1,
        mid,
        position = -1;
        int row = 2;
        bool found = false;

        while (!found && first <= last)
        {
            mid = (first + last) / 2;
            if (avg[row][mid] == number)
            {
                cout << "found at index " << mid << endl;
                found = true;
            }
            else if (avg[row][mid] > number)
                last = mid - 1;
            else
                first = mid + 1;
        }
```

Comment: Can you use an existing search function like `std::lower_bound` or `std::upper_bound`?

Comment: Reminder:  for a binary search to work properly, the data must be sorted first.

Comment: You say you have two rows. Using `row = 2` will not give you the second row. Array indexing is from 0. So `row = 0` will give you the ID, `row = 1` will give you the GPA.

Comment: @Jason I see now. You are correct. Will `cout << "found at index " << mid << endl;` display the GPA if I make that change?

Comment: @Mark Your programming style is close to C. I don't see much C++ in it? Would you be interested in having C++ style solution/advise? Or maybe consider changing the tag if it really is C?

Comment: @Elyasin this is for a C++ course I am taking

Comment: @Mark Oh, sorry. Alright. I guess you are still at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For binary search the data your searching on must be sorted. In your case the 2D array must be sorted by Student ID before you pass it to search.

If the deminsions of your array is [2][12] then when you do `row = 2` you are going out of bounds for the 2D array. C++ is 0 based indexing. If the ID is the first row you'll need to do `row = 0`. I've rewritten your code below with a few changes.

First: I removed the found variable since it isn't necessary (you can just use low < high and a break statement).

Second: Fixed out of bounds indexing assuming ID is the first row and GPA is second.

Third: Passed in the id to search for. Since you have a double array, I made the passed in ID to search for a double.

```
void search(double students[][COLUMNS], double id){
    int low(0), high(COLUMNS);
    int ID(0), GPA(1);  // Row 1 is ID (index 0), Row 2 is GPA (index 1).

    while (low <= high){
      int mid = (low+high)/2;
      if (students[ID][mid] < id)
        low = mid;
      else if (students[ID][mid] > id)
        high = mid;
      else {
        cout << "Found at index " << mid << " with GPA: " 
             << students[GPA][mid] << endl;
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

Edit: I might suggest instead of a 2D array, create an array of objects that store the students information. The below class should do just fine.

```
class Student{
   public:
     int ID;
     double GPA;
     Student(int id = 0, double gpa = 4.0):ID(id),GPA(gpa){}
     bool operator < (const Student& s){
       return ID < s.ID;
     }
}
```

Comment: thank you it worked great! How could I change the binary search function above to make it a insertion sort function?

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. I'm not sure it's that easy to turn a binary search into an insertion sort. Although I guess you could use binary search to do a form of insertion sort. The general idea of an insertion sort is to start with a sorted list (a list of size 1 is always sorted) and repeatedly insert the next element into the list in the correct position. So really you just need to find the position in the list where the next element should be (ie search for the right position). This might be better suited to being asked in another question for a complete answer.

Comment: Ok got it. Also, is there a way to add a counter in the binary search to be able to display how many comparisons was made for a search?

Comment: Yes. You just need to add a counter variable outside the while loop set it's value initially to 0 and then after `int mid = (low+hight)/2` add `++counter` then after the while loop `cout << counter << endl`. (This isn't the exact number of comparison operations since you might do 1 or 2 (ie there are 3 options: `<`, `>` and `==`) but it tells you how many positions where tested (which is probably what you want).